# How to get variables from threaded classes?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-class

I want to get a variable from a threaded class.

I tried this:

```
import threading

class myclass:
    class mysubclass:
        def __init__(self):
            self.var = "anything"
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.mysubclass)
        self.thread.start()
        
        print(self.thread.var)

myclass()
```

But it gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'var'
```

This does work with no thread, replace

```
self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.mysubclass)
self.thread.start()

print(self.thread.var)
```

with

```
self.newsubclass = self.mysubclass()
print(self.newsubclass.var)
```

and it just works.

How do I get a variable from a threaded class?

Comment: `self.thread` is a `Thread` object since it's created via `threading.Thread()`, thus you wouldn't expect it to have a `var` attribute. That `var` attribute exists for instances of `mysubclass()`, hence why it works for the replacement you suggest.

Comment: It's not clear why you are using a thread in the first place. All it does is create an instance of `mysubclass`, then terminate immediately.

Comment: chepner, I simplified the code to make the problem clear. What I actually want to do is to have Tkinter running in a subclass.